# Tag filter in GitHub Actions containing underscore

Tags: github, github-actions, glob

I am trying to get our GitHub Actions workflow to match tags that look like this:

```
package_name-v1.2.3-dev
```

I have split up the tag filter into two sections, since the last part is optional, so it looks like this:

```yaml
name: Publish packages
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*-v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+'
      - '*-v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+-[A-Za-z0-9]+'
```

But it never matches my `package_name-v1.2.3` tag.

I have also tried without the second part and with explicitly specifying characters for the first part:

```yaml
name: Publish packages
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '[a-z0-9_]+-v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+'
```

but then it doesn't work at all, then GitHub says:

```
push event contained invalid tags patterns: [a-z0-9_]+-v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+
```

If I remove the `_` it stops complaining, but I need the tag name to be able to contain underscore. Any ideas?

Comment: `*` should match everything except `/`, per https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet, so I'm surprised it doesn't match `_`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah, same! It could of course be something else too...
Here are the tags: https://github.com/spydon/melos-action-test/tags
And here is the action that is not triggering: https://github.com/spydon/melos-action-test/blob/main/.github/workflows/publish.yml

Comment: Both `'*-v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+'` and `'*-v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+-[A-Za-z0-9]+'` work fine. See [here](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/6832413034) and [here](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/6832423956). With explicit underscore, this pattern `'[a-z]+_[a-z]+-v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+'` does work too. See [here](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/6832584889). However, for character groups and ranges, an underscore throws that "**invalid tags patterns**" error. You might want to [open an issue](https://github.com/github/docs/issues/new/choose) for this.

Comment: Thanks for checking @Azeem! Could it be that it doesn't trigger for me because the tags are created by CI?

Comment: @spydon: Sure thing. Yes, that's probable. To do it programmatically, you can trigger it on `workflow_dispatch` event and provide the tag with an input parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Azeem! Seems like I'm stuck then, because pub.dev only allows publishing packages from actions triggered by a tag.

Comment: @spydon: You're welcome! What do you mean by "because pub.dev only allows publishing packages from actions triggered by a tag"? After creating tag in one workflow, you can simply trigger another one. I'm not sure how your above statement applies here.

Comment: "Pub.dev rejects publishing from GitHub Actions triggered without a tag."
I don't know how they do that, but if one tries to publish from an action that isn't triggered by a tag (and the tag needs to follow the structure that you've set up on you pub page), pub rejects it.

Comment: @spydon: You're using https://github.com/bluefireteam/melos-action and it has multiple examples without direct reference to tag. Can you please share the link or the actual error? Maybe, a new question all these details would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Azeem I'm developing the melos-action (the publishing part is currently not working), and testing it towards https://github.com/spydon/melos-action-test
Here you can see an example where I tried to publish without being triggered by a tag:
https://github.com/spydon/melos-action-test/actions/runs/6825331670/job/18562949520

"The calling GitHub Action is not allowed to publish, because: publishing is only allowed from 'tag' refType, this token has 'branch' refType. See https://dart.dev/go/publishing-from-github
Authentication failed!"

Comment: Right. Looks like the [`github.ref_type`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) is being used internally to enforce this by `melos` CLI.

Comment: `Could it be that it doesn't trigger for me because the tags are created by CI?`: How are you creating the tag today by CI? Are you using a github.token or a PAT? The workflow might indeed not being triggered due to the token permission used to create the tag.

Comment: @GuiFalourd yeah, that part we already figured out that it's the reason why it didn't trigger, and we don't want to use a PAT since it shouldn't have personal dependencies in the pipelines. The problem we continued talking about was why I can't manually trigger another action with `workflow_dispatch` and that is since pub is rejecting publishes that aren't coming from an action triggered by a tag.
@Azeem it is not something that `melos` does internally, so it must be something that the `dart-lang/setup-dart` does, or that they check on the pub.dev server-side somehow.

Comment: `since it shouldn't have personal dependencies in the pipelines`: What do you mean by that? Could it possibly be a service account token in that case? (service account = user account created for an organization or team, without specific owner, for internal processes)

Comment: Since all dependents of the action then have to create machine users (what GitHub calls service accounts) it seems like a bad solution.